# create-react-app npx WARN old lockfile error

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm facing this error while creating a react app. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling node.js a couple of times but it doesn't seem to work:
[image]
[image]
Then I also tried doing npm cache clean --force but it says:
"npm warn using --force recommended protections disabled"

Then I tried the create-react-app command again and I still get the same error.
I've been muddling over this for hours, any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me which version of node you are using ?

Comment: @JayPatel v14.17.6

Comment: try to use version 12

Comment: @JayPatel to download v12.22.6 do i have to download node.exe, node.lib, node_pdb.zip all of them? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: This solution from another stack overflow page helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62220411/16738349